# Calculate group variance while excluding current observation

Tags: r, variance

I have a data frame (DF),
That comprises of: grade and school id.

I'm trying to create a 'Var_grade' variable that  calculates the variance of the grades of all the other rows which belong to the same school, excluding the current one.
How could I do that in R?

for example-

[image: A table]

I tried to run this code-

```
DF<-DF %>% group_by(School)%>%
  mutate(Var_grade= combn(grade, (n()-1),  FUN=VAR))
```

but I got this error message-
The error occured in group 1: School = 1

Comment: Images are not a good way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(DF)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(DF, 20))`.

Comment: Your code should work if you just change `FUN=VAR` to `FUN=var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  group_by(School)%>%
  mutate(Var_grade = purrr::map_dbl(row_number(), ~var(grade[-.x])))

#  School grade Var_grade
#   <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1      1    90     112. 
#2      1    80      12.5
#3      1    95      50  
#4      2   100     108. 
#5      2    65     225  
#6      2    70     308. 
#7      2    85     358.
```

---

In base you can use `ave` with `sapply` :

```
DF$Var_grade <- with(DF, ave(grade, School, FUN = function(x) 
                     sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) var(x[-i]))))
```

**data**

```
DF <- data.frame(School = rep(1:2, c(3, 4)), 
                 grade = c(90, 80, 95, 100, 65, 70, 85))
```